# Parameter dont have value in webapi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I am trying to call a service through swagger, by passing a parameter in XML format.

Method is hitting, but the passed parameter is blank

Means "xlff" is blank. Do you have clue what wrong i am doing

```
/// <summary>
    /// Get or insert blog comments which is approved based on blogs
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks> Get or insert blog comments which is approved based on blogs</remarks>
    /// <param name="xlf">The comment.</param>
    /// <response code="200">Get approved blog comments</response>
    /// <response code="404">Not found</response>
    /// <returns>IHttpActionResult</returns>
    [Route("api/smartling/ProcessSmartlingTranslation")]
    [VersionedRoute("", 1)]
    [ResponseType(typeof(HttpResponseMessage))]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult ProcessSmartlingTranslation([FromBody]xliff xlff)
    {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Any object");
    }



 /// <summary>
    /// XliffModel created
    /// </summary>
    public class xliff
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// file getter setter method
        /// </summary>
        public string file { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// body getter setter method
        /// </summary>
        public string body { get; set; }
    }
```

[image: Swagger]

Comment: client side code would be usefull as well

Comment: i am using swagger why client side required?

Comment: It probably happened because cannot deserialize XML which you sending. Did you check is `xliff` compatibile with XML schema which you sending?

Comment: so show how you call this api. or youre definition in swagger

Comment: how to check this?

Comment: Are you able to pass in the XML format you're using from Postman? Goal is to see if the issue is specific to Swagger, or it's in your code / configuration of Web API. Also, does it work if you pass the model as JSON?

Comment: i have not tried that, i am trying to code to change the datatype to XML, give me 2 min

Comment: i have passed as string, but it came partially and cut it in the first line

Comment: i tried public IHttpActionResult ProcessSmartlingTranslation([FromBody]XElement xlff)  but no luck, its null again

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter content type is application/json, but you're sending xml. You should change the content type to application/xml.

Comment: how i will change this?

Comment: From swagger UI. Below your request xml you have the "Parameter request type" drop-down

Comment: i dont have xml there in the dropdown

Comment: Have you disabled xml formatter in your WebApiConfig?

Comment: i dont know the support is added for xml, where to check?